# PanGesture Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am presenting my side menu from the right side as opposed to the left using this code block here

```
 @objc func setupBarButtonItems(){
        let mainWindow  = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        //initial position of side menu
        menuController.view.frame = CGRect(x: maxX, y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: self.view.frame.height)
        mainWindow?.addSubview(menuController.view)
        addChildViewController(menuController)
        //add side menu button to nav bar
        let sideMenuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-Menu-48")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.rightBarPressed))
        let calendarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-calendar-50")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.presentCalendar))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [sideMenuButton,calendarButton]
    }

    @objc func addPanGesture(){
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    @objc func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        //will give you position of finger in swipe gesture
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        if gesture.state == .changed {
            var x = translation.x
            print(x)
            x = min(-menuWidth,x)
            x = max(0,-returnX)
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: x , y: 0)
            menuController.view.transform = transform
            navigationController?.view.transform = transform
        }else if gesture.state == .ended {
            rightBarPressed()
        }
        //drag out the menu controller

    }
```

However, my dragging is a little flawed. It accurately comes out but when I try to move it back it snaps back to the pulled out state. Im aware that swipes to the left are in the negative direction and vice versa for right. Any idea how I would change the min and max functions to make this work properly

I have added a lil gif to show current nature

[image]